# iphone developer program: does it require a business license?

Tags: iphone

Sorry, this is not programming related but I still think its important.

I know that for a company of 2 people or more the program requires a business license. Is it the same requirement for an individual developer releasing an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can sign up as an individual